# Find difference between values in one column/table and the value one rank lower in another table

Tags: mysql, sql

Customer Table

| CustID | SegmentID |
| --- | --- |
| 12345 | 69582 |
| 34567 | 52467 |
| 56789 | 52467 |
| 78912 | 52467 |

Contract Table

| rank | rev_attempted | attempt_ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 75 | 264578 |
| 2 | 65 | 264578 |
| 3 | 25 | 264578 |
| 1 | 45 | 789452 |

Winner Data

| attempt_ID | CustID | Revenue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 264578 | 12345 | 75 |
| 234567 | 34567 | 73 |
| 468751 | 56789 | 82 |
| 789452 | 78912 | 45 |

[Tables Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3NUhu.jpg)

[Fiddle Link](https://app.db-recruiter.com/session/45813535-bf2f-4bf4-9962-70ab853c2cd3)

Hello, apologizing in advance for struggling to articulate this. I have 3 tables with customer data, contract data, and winner data.

Customer data contains the individual customer and the segment they belong to.
Contract data is ranked by who I want to sell to and winner data is who won the contract (not always rank 1).

I want to find the marginal difference in revenue from the winner of the contract (in the winner table) and the rank below them (in the contract table) but I'm unsure of how to go about matching the record in the winner data table to the contract data table record, finding the record below (or if there is none) and subtracting that revenue attempted by the revenue won to get the margin. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

The desired output is as follows:

| CustID | Revenue | Marginal Revenue | Average Marginal Revenue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | 75 | 10 | 10 |
| 78912 | 45 | 45 | 45 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think something like this should work (didn't verify it on tables so there might be a little bit of name correction necessary). Hoping i got your problem right...

```
-- get rank of winners => Each row is winner per bet, that was engaged in (1:N)
WITH RankWinner AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT 
         Winner.ClientId
        ,Winner.call_attempt_id AS BidGroupId
        ,Bid.rank               AS Rank
        ,Winner.rev             AS Revenue
    FROM       ClientData AS Winner 
    INNER JOIN BidData    AS Bid    ON ClientData.call_attempt_id = BidData.call_attempt_id
    WHERE Winner.rev = Bid.rev_per_attempt
)

-- get "next best bets" per winner => Each row is bet per Winner
WITH MarginalRevenue AS (
    SELECT
         RankWinner.ClientId
        ,RankWinner.BidGroupId 
        ,RankWinner.Revenue
        ,RankWinner.Revenue - Bid.Revenue AS MarginalRevenue
    FROM      RankWinner
    LEFT JOIN (
        -- I'm using a Subquery here to get rid of duplicate ranks, just in case they're not unique.
        SELECT DISTINCT
            rank             AS Rank
            ,call_attempt_id AS GroupId
            ,rev_per_attempt AS Revenue
        FROM BidData)        AS Bid ON  RankWinner.Rank + 1   = Bid.Rank        -- Find the next lower rank from Winner rank
                                    AND RankWinner.BidGroupId = Bid.GroupId; 
)

-- aggregate on client
SELECT
     ClientId
    ,SUM(Revenue)         AS TotalRevenue
    ,SUM(MarginalRevenue) AS TotalMarginalRevenue
    ,AVG(MarginalRevenue) AS MarginalRevenue
    ,COUNT(BidGroupId)    AS NumberOfBids
FROM MarginalRevenue
GROUP BY ClientId
```

Comment: Hi @8bnjmn, thank you so much for helping get me unstuck on this problem. I was having a lot of issues with the logic on recursively joining the bids table to get the rank lower and your solution helped me figure it out. I only tweaked one table name and changed the rank - to rank + to get the rank below butr otherwise I think this solution is great. Thanks!

Comment: Ah, of course it's + 1! - Always better to test code before posting... Happy to help! :)